# running a Knn function in R

Tags: r, knn

[image]I have used the following code to run a Knn algorithm on my data set:

```
ran <- sample(1:nrow(Knn_data), 0.9*nrow(Knn_data))
nor <- function(x) { (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
Knn_data_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(Knn_data[,c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)], nor))
summary(Knn_data_norm)
Knn_train <- Knn_data_norm[ran,]
Knn_test <- Knn_data_norm[-ran,]
Knn_target_category <- Knn_data[ran,8]
Knn_test_category <- Knn_data[-ran,8]
library(class)
pr <- knn(Knn_train, Knn_test, cl=Knn_target_category, k=3)
```

I keep getting the error:
Error in knn(Knn_train, Knn_test, cl = Knn_target_category, k = 3) :  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
how do I change the class so that it is the same length?[image]

Comment: Is column 8 a "factor of true classifications of training set" as called for on the manual page? Are there any missing values in the data?

Comment: its either yes or no as refers to if it is a user or not and columns 1-7 are numbers, no data is missing

Answer (score 0):

Without the data there is no way to reproduce your results. Here is your code using the `iris` data set that comes with R. There are no problems:

```
data(iris) # Four measurements on three species with 50 observations of each
library(class)
set.seed(42)  # Make the example reproducible
ran <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 0.9*nrow(iris))
nor <- function(x) { (x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}
Knn_data_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(iris[,1:4], nor))
Knn_train <- Knn_data_norm[ran,]
Knn_test <- Knn_data_norm[-ran,]
Knn_target_category <- iris[ran, 5]
Knn_test_category <- iris[-ran, 5]
pr <- knn(Knn_train, Knn_test, cl=Knn_target_category, k=3)
table(Knn_test_category, pr)
#                  pr
# Knn_test_category setosa versicolor virginica
#        setosa          5          0         0
#        versicolor      0          6         0
#        virginica       0          1         3
```

14 of 15 are correctly predicted. Also note that `nrow(Knn_train)` is equal to `length(Knn_target_category)`. Your error message suggests this is not true for your data.

Comment: ITlooks like I need to transpose Knn_target_category but I'm not sure how I do that as the code I have used is exactly the same as the code you just gave me.

Comment: do you know how I can share my data if dput isn't retuning it in form summary()

Comment: I have added a screenshot too the data if that's any help as can't find a way of sharing it any other way

Comment: A screenshot is of no use. The output from `str(Knn_data)` might help. The whole purpose of `dput()` is to return the data in a format that can be copy/pasted. You do not have to use all of the data, eg. `dput(Knn_data[1:25, ])` and then run your code on this subset to see if you get the same error before posting it.  A summary of the data is not useful. What do `nrow(Knn_train)`  and `length(Knn_target_category)` return?